# Wrong MimeType when sending file on AWS AS2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-transfer-family

I'm trying to send a file to someone using AWS Transfer Faimly AS2 service.
I'm uploading a file to s3 bucket and when I download that file I can see that MimeType is "application/edifact".
When I send that file to AS2, on the log I see that MimeType is different.
How do I set MimeType to correct value?

I'm using latest Java & Spring AWS libraries.

Sending file to AS2 using SDK:

```
client.startFileTransfer(
        builder ->
            builder
                .connectorId(connectorId)
                .sendFilePaths(bucket + "/" + key)
    );
```

Sending file to AS2 using CloudShell:

```
aws transfer start-file-transfer --connector-id c-123 --send-file-paths "/bucket/file.edifact"
```

AS2 log:

```
{
  "status-code": "COMPLETED",
  "requester-content-type": "application/octet-stream",
  "transfer-size": 2658,
  "requester-file-name": "file.edifact",
  "as2-to": "RECIPIENT_ID",
  "as2-from": "SENDER_ID",
  "as2-message-id": "asdasdasd-asdasdasdads@asdasdasd",
  "transfer-id": "asdfasd-asd-asd-as-d-asdasd",
  "connector-id": "c-123",
  "file-path": "/bucket/file.edifact",
  "timestamp": "2024-03-25T11:35:30.435458Z"
}
```